# High CPU load - CentOS

Tags: python, centos, cpu

I have a high CPU load on a server. If do the command:

ps -eo pcpu,pid,user,args | sort -k1 -r | head -15

I get:

```
%CPU   PID USER     COMMAND
 5.0 29659 root     python ayre.py disease.co.il
 5.0 29620 root     python ayre.py discountcenter.co.il
 4.0 15656 root     python ayre.py callapp.co.il
 4.0 15644 root     python ayre.py call69.co.il
 4.0 15638 root     python ayre.py call4love.co.il
 4.0 15636 root     python ayre.py caliph.co.il
 4.0 15634 root     python ayre.py caligula.co.il
 4.0 29711 root     python ayre.py disrael.co.il
 4.0 29697 root     python ayre.py dismantlingvehicles.co.il
 4.0 29683 root     python ayre.py disk2disk.co.il
 4.0 29677 root     python ayre.py diskin.co.il
 4.0 29675 root     python ayre.py disi.co.il
 4.0 29657 root     python ayre.py disenchick.co.il
 4.0 29639 root     python ayre.py discoverisrael.co.il
```

I don't know what this is. I don't think this is good, but what is it and what can i do to stop this.

Comment: I suspect that you've been rooted.  However, this question is a more sysadmin / general computing question than it is programming-related so it’s *off-topic* for StackOverflow and more appropriate for [Unix and Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) or [Super User](http://superuser.com/).

Comment: Looks like domain names. I suppose somebody has broken into your server and is now trying to compromise others. You need to install it from scratch again. Use a strong password this time.